# How do I use Opaque Pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm going through the C book online, I don't understand 6.6 on struct pointers. I'm trying to return a pointer to a doubly linked list in an initialize function and have lost my way.

.h has an opaque pointer to reference doubly linked list(s):

```
typedef void * d_link_list_t;
```

.c implementation has the list struct definition:

```
    typedef struct list_s
    {
        node_t * head;
        node_t * tail;
        int count; //num nodes
    } list_t
```

.c later I have the implementation of the initialize function where problem is:

```
d_link_list_t* Initialize(void)
{
     //Converting opaque pointer to real pointer
      d_link_list_t* list = (d_link_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_link_list_t*));



     // Now make concrete list_t pointer and set the members
      list_t  * rlP;//real list pointer
      rlP = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
      rlP->head = NULL;
     rlP->tail = NULL;
     rlP->count = 1;

     //cast opaque pointer to real list P PROBLEM HERE
     list = (d_link_list_t*)rlP;
      list->count = 0; //list IS NOT STRUCT

      return list;
}
```

I want to return `* d_link_list_t` , an opaque pointer that will reference an instance of a linked list. I want all my functions in the implementation.c to use the list that this opaque pointer in the .h references.  I don't understand how to do that at all.

I tried just casting the opaque pointer to the list_t struct pointer - expecting the opaque pointer to point to the same place as the struct pointer but this seems wrong. Trying to access count with '->' gives the error "Trying to access member 'count' in something not a struct or union"

How can I make the void Opaque pointer reference my list_t struct? Please help me!

Comment: For an excellent article/tutorial on incomplete datatypes, encapsulation, data-hiding, dynamic linkage/late binding, opaque pointers and object oriented approaches to dynamic data-structures, see [**Object Oriented Programming in ANSI-C**](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf). And... do not cast the return of `malloc`, there is no need.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know it points to a struct, *which is precisely the point*. Rest assured that it does actually point to a struct, you just have to cast it back so the compiler will let you access that struct.

Comment: Thanks big time David! Section A.3 Generic Pointers - void * for reference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hey, do you have a different link to the pdf? I'm getting a 403 forbidden.

Comment: @thepufferfish Hey, that wasn't like that when I posted it. [Object Oriented Programming in ANSI-C](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf) This link is good. All sample code is on [github - ooc](https://github.com/shichao-an/ooc)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the mirror link, David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
d_link_list_t* list = (d_link_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_link_list_t*));
```

It allocates the wrong amount of memory. You need to allocate the size of the thing being pointed to, not the size of the pointer.

However this is a bad idea anyway. The function should be:

```
d_link_list_t Initialize(void)
{
// Now make concrete list_t pointer and set the members
    list_t  * rlP;
    rlP = malloc(sizeof(*rlP));
    rlP->head = NULL;
    rlP->tail = NULL;
    rlP->count = 1;        

    return rlP;
}
```

Not sure what you were trying to do with `list->count = 0;`, because `list` has an opaque type, that is not possible.   Also unclear why you write `rlP->count = 1` instead of `= 0`.

If you want to use pointer syntax (i.e. `d_link_list_t *`) then you should remove the `*` from the typedef line.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a few problems. Firstly, d_link_list_t is already a void pointer so when you are defining your opaque pointer use

```
d_link_list_t list; //list is a void pointer

and not

d_link_list_t* list; //list is a pointer to a void pointer.
```

Secondly, I think this code

```
//Converting opaque pointer to real pointer
d_link_list_t* list = (d_link_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_link_list_t*));
```

is supposed to allocate space for the opaque pointer but you don't need to do that, as I said before just use

```
d_link_list_t list; //list is a void pointer.
```

Thirdly, you will also need to adjust your cast, at the end of the function, when you cast the real pointer to a opaque pointer. Use

```
list = (d_link_list_t)rlP;
```

instead of

```
list = (d_link_list_t*)rlP;
```

Finally, at the very end, why are you trying to access the contents of the struct through the opaque pointer. Why this

```
list->count = 0; //list IS NOT STRUCT
```

The whole idea of creating an opaque pointer is so that the user can not directly access the struct. If you want to access the struct use the real pointer or cast the opaque pointer to a pointer to the struct. Again the whole idea is to hide the internal implementation of your list from the user of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `(void *)`, you should simply use

```
typedef struct list_s list_t;
```

in your header file, and define the `struct list_s` in your .c file.

Answer (score 1):

An opaque pointer is like the C `FILE` structure. In Microsoft C, the `FILE` structure is

```
typedef struct _iobuf {
    void *_Placeholder;
} FILE;
```

Notice how none of the actual fields are there--instead the only member is a `void *`. This pointer actually points to a secret structure located deep in the Microsoft C implementation. Lets say it looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    int cnt;
    char *ptr;
    char *base;
    int flag;
    int fd;
} impfile;
```

The functions that operate on `FILE` pointers then cast the `_Placeholder` member into an `impfile` structure. For example, a function to access the file descriptor would look like this:

```
int getfd(FILE *fp)
{
    return ((impfile *) fp->_Placeholder)->fd;
}
```

The Windows API uses a similar technique, via handles, like `HWND`.

The advantage to this approach is that users cannot access any of the private members. This also allows APIs to change without breaking any existing code, since you know nobody can tamper with the structure's privates.

This can also be applied in C++ using the [Handle Body Idiom](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=242).